# What's the proper naming convention for my table in cake php

Tags: database-design, cakephp, naming-conventions

I have an images table and tags table. I also want to have a tags_map table that will map images from images table with tags in tags table. So instead of naming my table tags_map, I would have to name it tags_maps by CakePhp conventions?

```
CREATE TABLE images ( id INT NOT NULL auto_increment, image MEDIUMBLOB NULL, user_id INT NOT NULL, timestamp TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, PRIMARY KEY(id) );

CREATE TABLE tags ( id INT NOT NULL auto_increment, tag_name VARCHAR(255), PRIMARY KEY(id), UNIQUE(tag_name) );

CREATE TABLE tags_maps ( id INT NOT NULL auto_increment, tag_id INT NOT NULL, image_id INT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id) );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HABTM tables with an `image_id` column and a `tag_id` column should be named `images_tags` according to [Cake conventions](http://book.cakephp.org/view/903/Model-and-Database-Conventions). If you choose anything else, like "map", you're already deviating from the conventions and need to explicitly configure the table name in the model anyway.